# How to add a new line into a .c file with unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I am looking to do a simple modification to my unix shell by editting the start up print functions to say my name, I have located the main.c file and i have located the line (325) where i would like to insert it, I have used sed and awk for this however neither seems to work, the closest i have seemed to have got is writing the line:

```
$ sed '326 i/
>   My name' main.c
```

This then peints out the main.c file however then when i go to search for my name or look through thr file using less, the line has not been inserted, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: That `sed` command is sending its modified output to standard output. If you want it to edit the file you need to use the `-i` flag or redirect the output to a (different) file and then swap the files yourself.

Comment: Ok great thanks, where would the -i tag go? Would it be instead of i/

Comment: See `man sed` and about a thousand questions on this site and many many other pages on the internet.

Comment: Without details about how you determined the line number, this is speculative, but frequently, a `sed` or Awk program which figures out from context which line to change, and then immediately changes it, is often a better solution than dividing the problem into too-small pieces.

Comment: The follow up question here is, of course, why you want to do this with `sed` instead of a normal text editor and why you want to change this in the source of the shell and not with a shell startup script (unless this is a custom shell and it doesn't support that concept).

Comment: I used grep to find the line in the code that i wanted to change, and i was simply trying to get used to the language and thought this would be something fun to try, thanks for your help

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the C language, suggest removing the 'c' tag

Answer (score 1):

To insert a newline after line 326:

```
sed '326s/$/\n/' main.c
```